# Optimal picking strategy for matrix of probabilities

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory

Let's say, I have a matrix of probabilities. Each row represents an event and columns represents probabilities of possible outcomes for that event. For example:

```
  4%  30% 35% 31%
  34% 18% 21% 27%
  25% 19% 21% 35%
  29% 14% 25% 32%
```

I must pick 1, 2, 3 or even 4 outcomes from each row. So, for example if I choose ALL, then the chance to predict every event outcome is 100%.

In general the task is to make as less as possible picks to have the best chance to predict all of the events.

I guess there are some ready solutions, but I'm not sure how to formulate the problem to find them.

Comment: I think the answer is dependent on the "marginal penalty" for each additional probability chosen.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right and it answers your question, but its result of multiplying the number of elections.

Comment: In mathematics you may view that as a constrained optimization problem, and statistical testing have similar nature inside. You want to maximize the probability of correct prediction. This probability probably is your objective function. You may consider whether a partially correct prediction is also included. Then your constraint, as mentioned above, is the number of picks. If there is no such constraint, no penalty, then you may choose all as you said. So you need to formulate this as well.

Comment: For example, if the events are independent, and you consider the overall prediction probability only, then each row you should pick the mode, the one with largest probability, and the remaining task is to allocate the remaining picks to maximize it (and it is ugly). Note the number of picks is fixed. The dual problem is to find the minimum number of picks so that the overall prediction probability exceed a certain level. So it depends on your formulation.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the problem is not to exceed a certain level, the problem is to somehow maximize the value of each pick, considering the multiplication effect - I mean if we make 2 picks for each of 4 events its 8 picks, but costs 2*2*2*2 = 16, however if we choose 4 for 1 event and 1 for all others its 7 picks, but costs just 4*1*1*1 = 4.

Comment: You need to somehow relate this "cost" to the "gain" of making correct predictions. So far, you've only told us about the cost and the gain, but not how to relate them to each other. Unless you quantify this, we don't know e.g. whether a solution with cost $6$ and prediction probability $0.5$ is better or worse than a solution with cost $8$ and prediction probability $0.7$.